# Saving .py current code to a specific folder

Tags: python

Is it possible to save the current code of my program to a specific folder? 
Telling the computer to save the .py file to a created folder in a absolute path.

Comment: You mean that "copy the `.py` file to another folder",right?

Comment: better straight save the .py file

Answer (score 0):

Something like... simply making a copy of your current py file? Like this?

```
with open(__file__, "r") as src:
    with open("some_full_path_you_want_to_copy_this_to.py", "w") as tgt:
        tgt.write(src.read())
```

Comment: and ``os.remove(__file__)`` to remove the origin file.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA - he has mentioned "save", not "move", so probably not. In any case, i'd think twice before making my scripts erase themselves :-)